# Create new object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array of object

```
[{id: 1, options[{...}]}, {id:2, options[{...}] }, {id: 3, options[{...}]
```

How I can create new object filtered by id for example. (using javascript)

singleObject = {id:2, options[{...}]}

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, you can also use `Array.find` to find something

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293290/sorting-nested-arrays-of-objects-by-date

Comment: @GalAbra that question is about *sorting* not *finding*.

Comment: you can use Array.filter to filter the array like result = arrayObj.filter(obj => obj.id == 2);

Comment: Thanks. It's help :)